# Spring bean dependency on same instance of object

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-bean

I have 3 beans, configured in XML as follows.

```
<bean id="classA" class="com.petehallw.test.MyClassA">
    <constructor-arg name="threadPoolFactory" ref="threadPoolFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg name="classB" ref="classB"/>
</bean>

<bean id="classB" class="com.petehallw.test.MyClassB"/>

<bean id="threadPoolFactory" class="come.petehallw.test.MyThreadPoolFactory"/>
```

You can see that two dependencies are injected into `MyClassA` - `classB` and `threadPoolFactory`.

In `MyClassA`, there is a call to `MyClassA.threadPoolFactory.getThreadPool()` that returns a new object of type `ThreadPoolExecutor`, assigned to a member variable of `MyClassA`.

My question is, how can I give `MyClassB` a reference to the same instance of `ThreadPoolExecutor` if a new instance is returned from that method? Is this something I can do via bean configuration, or am I forced to add a setter method to `MyClassB`? I ask because `MyClassB` should always have a non-null `ThreadPoolExecutor` (of the same instance referred to by `MyClassA`) so really it should be passed in via the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Since the default scope for a bean is singleton. You can either use setter or constructor injection to refer the threadpool in ClassB. Hence in your case The following config should suffice.

```
<bean id="classB" class="com.petehallw.test.MyClassB">
    <constructor-arg name="threadPoolFactory" ref="threadPoolFactory"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can see how that would give me the same instance of  `MyThreadPoolFactory` but it won’t help me share the same instance of `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: @petehallw  How are you injecting threadpool in your factory class `MyThreadPoolFactory` I believe you are using some bean to inject the same. You can use the same bean in your classB

Comment: I am instantiating a new instance with the `new` operator in the method. So it's not being injected as a bean reference.

Comment: Well that's what you need to change. Spring container can only manage beans which are declared in your XML file since your are using it